# What is the best way to move millions of data from one postgres database to another?

Tags: postgresql

So we have a task at the moment where I need to move millions of records from one database to another.

To complicate things slightly I need to change an id on each record before inserting the data.

How it works is we have 100 stations in `database a`.
Each station contains `30+` sensors.
Each sensor contains readings for about the last 10 years.
These readings are anywhere from 15minute interval to daily interval.
So each station can have at least `5m` records.

`database b` has the same structure as `database a`.
The reading table contains the following fields

```
id: primary key
sensor_id: int4
value: numeric(12)
time: timestamp
```

What I have done so far for one station is.

1. Connect to `database a` and select all readings for `station 1`
2. Find all corresponding sensors in `database b`
3. Change the `sensor_id` from `database a` to it's new `sensor_id` from `database b`
4. Chunk the `updated sensor_id` data to groups of about `5000` parameters
5. Loop over the chunks and do a mass insert

In theory, this should work.
However, I am getting errors saying `duplicate key violates unique constraint`.
If I query the database on those records that are failing, the data doesn't exist.

The weird thing about this is that if I run the script 4 or 5 times in a row all the data eventually gets in there.  So I am at a loss as to why I would be receiving this error because it doesn't seem accurate.

Is there a way I can get around this error from happening?
Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe it is a different constraint than the one you had in mind. But then it also can be that two of the rows you are trying to insert are in conflict with each other, and both inserts are rolled back.

Comment: it could possibly, but if i keep running the same script over and over, all the data eventually does get in, so that tells me that the data is all ok

Comment: You have to debug this: log the values you insert, and when you hit the error, compare the values of the failing insert with the other inserted values and the pre-existing values in the table. The question contains too little information to be able to tell what is wrong. You can exclude a database bug in such a trivial matter, but index corruption cannot be excluded with absolute certainty. Rebuild the primary key index to make sure.

Comment: I had done, the values where not duplicate, it seemed to have something to do with the multiple inserts in one go.  Using `COPY` instead seemed to do the trick